# Node JS - res.locals is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

In my node js app i am using a function as a middleware in some routes. I usually used res.locals as a `function` in order not to override the `res.locals` object. But now I updated nodejs and express to latest versions and Idon't know why i'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.locals is not a function
    at /home/jose/workspace/tfg/server.js:116:8
    at tryCatcher (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:11:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:491:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:548:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:593:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:672:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:125:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:135:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/jose/workspace/tfg/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

What this middleware does is shown below:

```
function middle_datos (req, res, next){

    var id_usuario = req.user ? req.user._id : 'undefined';

    // object to override res.locals
    var variables_locales = {
        ip: IP,
        message: JSON.stringify({
            error: req.flash('error'),
            success: req.flash('success'),
            info : req.flash('info'),
        }),
        title: 'Informa Torrent',
        subtitle: 'La app con la que podrás contribuir a la mejora de Torrent.',
        user: req.user, 
        id_usuario: id_usuario
    };

    db.query(queries.obtener_datos_app) // consultamos los datos de la app
        .then (function(datos_app){

            variables_locales.datos_app = datos_app; // obtenemos datos app

            if (! req.user) throw new Error('no estás loggeado'); // Si no hay usuario conectado --> Continuamos adelante
                                               // ya que no consultamos notificaciones ni acciones  

            return db.query(queries.obtener_notificaciones, req.user._id); // consultamos notificaciones

        })
        .then(function(notificaciones){
            // obtenemos notificaciones
            variables_locales.mis_notificaciones = notificaciones; // ls pasamos al objeto res.locals

            return db.query(queries.obtener_acciones, req.user._id); // consultamos acciones

        })
        .then (function(acciones){
            // obtenemos acciones
            variables_locales.mis_acciones = acciones;
            res.locals(variables_locales); // Error
            next(); // siguiente ruta o middleware
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error middleware ' + error); // print the error;
            res.locals(variables_locales);
            next(); // siguiente ruta o middleware
        });

};
```

So, what is the problem with res.locals ?

Also if I try to push some key-value to res.locals in that way:

```
res.locals.someKey = someValue;
```

I can't access that variable from my jade template.

Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`res.locals` isn't a function. So you should set your variables like this:

```
res.locals = variables_locales;
```

And for the JADE template, you probably have to pass the res.locals variable to the rendering engine:

```
res.render('index', {
    locals: res.locals
});
```

And then access the variable in JADE like this:

```
p= locals.title
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and works perfect! I realize that there's no need to pass res.locals to jade.

Answer (score 0):

My `i18n.js`

```
const i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({
  locales:['en', 'iw'],
  directory: __dirname + '/locales',
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  cookie: 'lang',
});

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.__ = i18n.__;
  return next();
};
```

Or we can resolve using `res.locals.__ = res.__;`